# Load JSON before anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to load the JSON before anything else loads, because I need to access the JSON immediately when a browser connects to the server.

This is how I load my json

```
$.getJSON('icons.txt', function(iconData) {
    icons = iconData;
});
```

How can I make it so javascript loads the json first before anything else? or at least makes it so that it's loaded before the user connects.

Comment: $.getJSON returns a promise object. If you want to do something after 1 or multiple json files are loaded, make use of $.when api and pass the promise objects returned from $.getJSON calls, $.when will give you a callback after all the jsons are loaded. `$.when` -> https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/  `$.getJSON` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Just put all your other code inside `function(iconData) {icons = iconData;});` callback function, it will be executed after the JSON will be fetched.

Comment: I should put all my code inside the `$.getJSON`? What if I'd where to use `$.getJSON` twice..

Comment: @MartijnEbbens, if you want to execute some code AFTER the JSON will be fetched, you need to put this code inside callback function (`function(iconData) {icons = iconData;});` in your case). `.getJSON` is an asynchronous operation, if you will just put the code after it, this code will be executed before the JSON fill be fetched. If you want to call `getJSON` twice or more, you can wrap other code in function and invoke it like this: `$.getJSON('icons.txt', function(iconData) {stuffToDoAfterJsonFetched()});`

Answer (score 0):

If you put your  tag in the head of your HTML, it should be executed at first.

Maybe duplicate of: [Load javascript before rendering page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5642233/load-javascript-before-rendering-page)

Comment: How can I then access the JSON from the file?

Comment: Well you can use the dom after to use the json you just fetch.

Comment: So I could just paste the code in the HTML `Head` and it would work..?

Answer (score 0):

The code loaded on the head, and then set to synchronize loading

```
$.ajaxSettings.async = false;
$.getJSON(url, data, function(data){ });
```

Comment: How can I then access the JSON from the file?

Comment: Yeah, that works but I do get a Deprecation. `[Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.`

Comment: This error is understandable because you are loading a file synchronously and will wait for the file to be loaded after the code continues.